# Toolstripmenuitem not running method C#

Tags: c#

I have a method that foreaches a row within a datagridview and starts a process. However, when I click the toolstripmenuitem to execute the method it does not work. Any suggestions?

[image]

This is the toolstripmenuitem ^

```
private void sIGNATUREToolStripMenuItem_DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.ManageContactsView == "STACKED")
    {
        ViewSignature(AllContacts);
    }
    else if (Properties.Settings.Default.ManageContactsView == "LISTED")
    {
        ViewSignature(AllContactsLISTED);
    }
    else
    {
        ViewSignature(AllContactsFULL);
    }
}
```

This is the code that is placed in the menu items click property ^

```
    void ViewSignature(DataGridView AllContacts)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in AllContacts.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row1.Cells[18].Value))
                {
                    Process.Start(Properties.Settings.Default.ReferencePoint + @"/Contacts/Contact_" + row1.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + @"/Signature.jpg");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Error message if the system cannot remove the contact from the database.
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.\n\nERROR CODE: BINSPIRE1009", "BLUEBERRY INSPIRE 2022", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the method I am trying to execute which fetches a column and row value from the datagridview and starts a process.

Comment: Have you already check the Event Porperties of that ToolStripItem if the method is correctly bind to it's click event?

Comment: Wrong event handler. Handle the `Click` event. Select that item and double click on to create the default click event handler. Use the `DropDownItemClicked` event to let a parent of dropdown items receive the click events of it's first level items.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I used the 'Click' event handler first. However, this did not work so I tried the 'Clicked' handler and neither did this.